# How to send nested raw JSON in URLSession to Vapor API?

Tags: json, swift, vapor, urlsession

I have a Vapor API that has a route to register users. This route recibes a nested object in JSON format like this:

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "email": "test1@test.com",
    "password": "Test1",
    "phone": {
        "numberString": "+52 999 999 9999",
        "countryCode": 52,
        "nationalNumber": 9999999999,
    }
}
```

This JSON is converted into a Content/Codable Object:

```
final class Create: Codable, Content {
    let name: String!
    let email: String!
    let password: String
    let phone: PhoneNumber!
    
    init(name: String, email: String, password: String, phone: PhoneNumber) {
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.phone = phone
    }
}
```

I have tried this route sending the JSON string as raw via Postman and the route worked perfectly but the problem is when I try to send it via URLSession in my iOS counterpart the ErrorMiddleware throws a DecodingError:

*DecodingError: Value of type 'String' required for key 'password'.*

At first I thought that the problem was the JSON generation until, for test purpose I send the same JSON as in the example and the Vapor API is still throwing the Error.

```
let urlStr = "\(BaseURL)/api/student/register"

guard let url = URL(string: urlStr) else { return }

var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy:
    .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 30.0)


let raw = "{\"name\":\"Prueba\",\"email\":\"prueba1@hotmail.com\",\"password\":\"Prueba1\",\"phone\":{\"numberString\":\"\",\"countryCode\":,\"nationalNumber\":}}"

urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
urlRequest.httpBody = raw.data(using: .utf8)

urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
    ...
}.resume()
```

Can you even send this types of JSON's via URLSession or do I need to change my logic so it will receive a flat array?

Comment: It is ok for vapor to receive and decode any complex json. On iOS side you could use JSONEncoder or I’d suggest CodyFire lib.

Comment: I first was using JSONEncoder, it didn't work either. I even printed the result of JSON encoder and paste it on Postman and worked fine. my guess is that it has to do in the way iOS is sending the JSON. @imike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours of debugging and getting strange errors I realized that my error was simpler than I thought.
The error was:

```
{"error":true, "reason":"Value of type 'String' required for key 'password'."}
```

And I tried to send in Postman a request with out the key 'password' which returned:

```
{"error": true, "reason": "Value required for key 'password'."}
```

What got me to analyze my objects and then I saw the error, my Create object wasn't unwrapped correctly, more precisely this:

```
let password: String
```

Should be having a *!* next to *String* like this.

```
let password: String!
```

The reason why this worked on Postman and not on URLSession is still uncleared.

**UPDATE:**

As proposed by @vadian the headers in this URLSession are also missing and even tho after I added the force unwrapped the API passed the request but with nil content

```
 urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField:"Accept")
 urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")
```

Answer (score 2):

Set also the content-type and length header

```
 urlRequest.setValue(String(Data(json.utf8).count), forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Length")
 urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField:"Accept")
 urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")
```

And never, never, never declare properties in a class as implicit unwrapped optional which are initialized with non-optional values.

Comment: You're right! the headers where also missing. @vadian